# get the last communication data between two people in MySQL database

Tags: mysql

Imagine we have a `table` with following message between users

```
sender-id    receiver_id       mssg   
-----------------------------------
1               2               m1
1               3               m2
2               1               m3
1               4               m4
4               1               m5
4               2               m6
4               1               m7
```

I want a result of talking of a user with others in `MySQL`
the same as what chat application have
For user 1 we should have

```
[mssg chat counter]       chat with user id       last mssg
   ------------------------------------------------------
2                            2                          m3
1                            3                          m2
3                            4                          m7
```

Comment: Do you have a primary key or timestamp to define the last message ?

Comment: yes there is a id and timestamps, the main problem for me is how to group them

Comment: what would be `mssg chat counter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `id` column which is `UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT` you can use this query then:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17a9f/7

```
SELECT m1.*, m.mssg
FROM (
  SELECT IF(messagies.sender_id=1, messagies.receiver_id,messagies.sender_id) as opponent,
    COUNT(*), MAX(messagies.id) id
  FROM messagies
  WHERE messagies.sender_id=1 
    OR messagies.receiver_id=1
  GROUP BY opponent ) m1

LEFT JOIN messagies m
ON m.id  = m1.id
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you want to `GROUP BY` the `sender_id` and `receiver_id` columns, and get the row with the maximum `timestamp` column.

```
SELECT sender_id, receiver_id, mssg AS last_mssg, MAX(timestamp)
FROM messages
GROUP BY sender_id, receiver_id;
```

By specifying the `MAX(timestamp)` in your query, MySQL will only fetch the row that matches that when it compiles it into the `GROUP BY`, thereby conveniently getting your desired result.

Comment: fields in the select list that are not part of the group by clause may return any value present in its group.